# Set data attribute of item inside v-for

Tags: vue.js

I have a loop to create a bootstrap accodion.

I'm getting errors for doing this part:
     **data-target="#collapse{{index}}**

```
 <div v-for="(section, index) in model.Sections" class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-accordion" data-target="#collapse{{index}}">
```

within the for, there will be another dv:

```
<div id="collapse{{index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, just figured it:

v-bind:data-target="'#collapse'+index"